# I am getting this error related to logging

Tags: python, logging, python-2.6

No handlers could be found for logger reports_wrapper

```
if logging.getLogger().hasHandlers():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
else:
    logger = logging.getLogger("reports_wrapper")
    streamHandler = logging.StreamHandler() 
    streamHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    streamHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(streamHandler)
```

then when i am trying to do

logging like logging.info("abc") , i am getting the error that no  handlers could be found  for reports_wrapper

Comment: Why are you using Python 2.6? That's now 13 years old and completely unsupported

Comment: @roganjosh maybe instead of lambasting OP for using a particular version of Python (which may or may not be in their control) a solution or workaround could be offered?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Apparently you are entering the first branch and the logger you are trying to use is only set up in the second branch.

Comment: @gold_cy lambasting? Rather than pulling me up on a sincere question and statement of fact (this is now _lambasting_?), a solution or workaround could be offered? There is no [mcve].